# Pulling info from one tab to another tab in excel

Tags: excel

I created a drop down box in tab entitled CHECKING CHASE from a list of categories in another tab called BUDGET. So I insert an amount of each withdrawal and then choose the category (MISC., RENT, CAR, etc).

Now I want each amount I put in the CHECKING CHASE tab to populate into the BUDGET tab under a specific column.

For instance - I pay rent for $700, then choose the category RENT. I want it to automatically move the $700 into my actual spent cell beside RENT in the BUDGET tab. Then I can see what I spent for each category.

Make sense?

Comment: Copy - but continue to add too. So if I buy something for $1 on the 1st under MISC. Then something on the 3rd for $3 under MISC. I want the total to show $4 in that cell.

Comment: Okay - thought I would give it a shot in hopes the answer was simple. Thanks!

Comment: Ha. Is there a better way to ask or more info I could give. Can I attach the file?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider the following solution without resorting to VBA.  Referring to the layout in the image:

[image: Sheet Layout]

Create an Excel Table and include headings.  You can produce an example layout first and then 'convert' it into a Table if you wish (Insert > Table > Insert).  This will allow you you add rows to the end of it when entering new withdrawals.

If you want dropdowns - I have used a simple Data Validation - List which is populated from a list of items in a Budget Sheet, cells A2:A5 in this example (Data > Data Tools > Data Validation > Settings > Allow: > List).  You can type in your values in the Data Validation dialogue, if you didn't want to use the separate Budget sheet.

Put the formula in cell C2 and format as you wish e.g. currency?

Highlight the Table headings and apply the filter arrows (Data > Sort & Filter > Filter)

Format to suit.

You now have the ability to extend the Table by just typing into the next available row underneath the Table and filter on Category (or categories), Date (or Dates) and/or Amount (or Amounts) and get the sub-total to show in cell C2.

If you want to exclude particular withdrawals (rows) from your sub-total amount, lets say a particular Misc withdrawal from all the Misc withdrawals in a particular month, then simply hide that row(s).  You can then unhide the row to restore full 'reporting'.

Also, if you wanted to re-designate an expenditure, simply reset the dropdown and the subtotals will adjust automatically.  This will absolve you from trying to keep two sheets in sync.

What this cannot do as presented is to give you a summary for all months, or all categories at once.  However, to achieve this, you could copy the Table to another Range/Sheet, remove the Table and apply SubTotals (Data > Outline > Subtotal)- see the image below:

[image: SubTotal Summary]

Note: to remove a Table click anywhere within the Table and in the Table Tools design context menu, in the Tools group select 'Convert to Range'.